# Transformation of an array yields an empty placeholder

Tags: arrays, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a numpy array called `new_input_processed`. The code below transforms it into a one hot array of type float32 (cf `byte_list`). But when I type `byte_list` to see the values of this array, I get an empty tensor. I would like to have a non-empty tensor instead. Is it possible ?

```
In [30]: new_input_processed
Out[30]: 
array([[ 83, 111, 109, 101,  32,  83, 101, 113, 117, 101, 110,  99, 101,
         32, 111, 102,  32,  99, 104,  97, 114,  97,  99, 116, 101, 114,
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8)

In [31]: byte_list = tf.cast(tf.one_hot(new_input_processed, 256, 1, 0), dtype=tf.float32)

In [32]: byte_list
Out[32]: <tf.Tensor 'Cast_2:0' shape=(1, 100, 256) dtype=float32>
```

Comment: how do you know its empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting an empty tensor. The Tensor object info is returned properly with:

```
<tf.Tensor 'Cast_2:0' shape=(1, 100, 256) dtype=float32>
```

Look at the shape, it is just as expected.

Nevertheless, if you want to see the content (i.e. the actual value of the `byte_list` Tensor object), one way is to call [eval()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor).

Something like this should do:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
new_input_processed = np.array([[ 83, 111, 109, 101,  32,  83, 101, 113, 117, 101, 110,  99, 101,
                                  32, 111, 102,  32,  99, 104,  97, 114,  97,  99, 116, 101, 114,
                                  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
                                  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
                                  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
                                  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
                                  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
                                  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=np.uint8)

byte_list = tf.cast(tf.one_hot(new_input_processed, 256, 1, 0), dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.Session() as sess:  print(byte_list.eval())  # here
```

**Output:**

```
[[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  ...
  [1. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I misunderstood the message returned by tensorflow